# Segmentation fault in destructor

Tags: c++, list, segmentation-fault, destructor

I get a segmentation fault when I try to execute my project. At the end of main where the destructor of the `Btree` class is run it calls the destructor of the `Node` class. Then in the destructor call of the `Word` class I get the error. And `list.tcc` opens `(~Btree -> ~Node() -> ~Word() (error): list.tcc:)`

Cursor gives error in this line:

`list.tcc:`

```
_Node* __cur = static_cast<_Node*>(this->_M_impl._M_node._M_next);
```

Is the reason of this error the list in the `Word` class?

The classes's codes abbreviated as below:

```
class Btree{
private:
...
Node *root;
...
public:...
~Btree(){delete[] root;};

};
```

---

```
class Node{
...
Word *words;
Node **children;
...
    ~Node(){delete [] words; delete []children;};
};
```

---

```
class Word{
public:
string word;
list<Couple> couple;

    Word(){};
    ~Word(){};
};
```

---

```
class Couple{
...
public:
....
    ~Couple(){};
 };
```

Comment: `delete[]` on a pointer that is not an array? Or is it an array?

Comment: why don't you declare your field `std::vector<Node> root;` ???

Comment: Did you use `valgrind` and `gdb` to debug your code, and did you compile it with `g++ -Wall -g`  (assuming you use Linux)??

Comment: Why don't you use smart pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you allocate your `root`? My personal guess would be that you allocate it using

```
root = new Node();
```

If you try to deallocate a non-array object as an array object, you will get undefined behavior. Practically, it would take the word right before the start of your node and assume it is a count of elements and destroy that number of elements. Since there is just one this bound not to work too well. You probably want

```
delete root;
```